# compare 2 files delete duplicate lines batch

Tags: sorting, batch-file, duplicates

Hope this is not a duplicate question.
I need a batch script for removing duplicate lines in multiple files. As input I have file1 and file2,3,4,5,6 ......the lines in files are sorted, 1 word per line. I need to remove from file 2,3,4,5... every line that is already in file 1, file 1 will work as dictionary for other files, only compares with1.

```
$ file1
12-bk-34652
13-bk-36789
14-bk-76559

$file2
12-bk-34652
12-bk-36098
13-bk-36789
14-bk-76559

output file2 > 12-bk-36098
```

For now I'm using this code and running files one by one.Also is kind of slow considering every file has around 50MB and file1 almost 200MB

```
       findstr /v /x /g:file1 file2>file2a
```

Comment: Technically it cannot be a duplicate question because it is a request. Here at Stack Overflow we expect you to create your own script, and post it here with sufficient information and detail to help you with any issues you have with it.